# How to remove first line text from text-box?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

What wrong with my code as below:

```
Select Case chkSTC.Checked
        Case True
            txtCargoDescription.Text = Resources._Global.ContrSTC & vbNewLine & txtCargoDescription.Text

        Case False
            Dim b As String() = Split(txtCargoDescription.Text, vbNewLine)
            txtCargoDescription.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, b, 1, b.Length - 1)                
    End Select
```

As I refer to other reference,

```
Dim b As String() = Split(txtCargoDescription.Text, vbNewLine)
txtCargoDescription.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, b, 1, b.Length - 1)
```

show that can remove the first line of multi-line from text-box, BUT it remove all text inside the text-box. Please help me to fix this.

Thank you in advanced :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is works if I use

```
txtCargoDescription.Text = txtCargoDescription.Text.Replace(Resources._Global.ContrSTC, "").Trim()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your text box to multiline=true

Answer (score 1):

Its working for me
In C#.net

```
 string[] sep = new string[] {"\r\n"};
 string[] lines = TextBox1.Text.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 TextBox1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", lines.Skip(1).ToList());
```

In vb.net

```
Dim sep() As String = New String() {""& vbCrLf}
Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(""& vbCrLf, lines.Skip(1).ToList)
```

Comment: I have checked it by write code (Asp.net C#.net) and it works 100%

Comment: actually the condition was if user checked the box, then "Container STC:-" will appear, but if user unchecked, "Cotanainer STC:-" should be remove.

Comment: inside `{""}` do I need to put something?